# RequestParameter in Ampscript and how it is used?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a html form and from this form we fetch email address.

For example, the form input field looks like this,

```
<input type="text" name="EmailAddress">
```

Then there is the amp-script code to fetch information from the form on submit

```
set @EmailAddress = Replace(RequestParameter("EmailAddress")," ","+") 

if empty(@EmailAddress) then set @EmailAddress = Replace(RequestParameter("email")," ","+") endif
```

This is built by someone in our team in the past and I am trying to understand what exactly the ampScript does here with replace? I am totally not able to understand this part. I only know that EmailAddress Filed is being fetched form input. Please can anyone help me understand this . Thanks

Comment: before asking on the forum, I would suggest you take a look at available resources that you can find either on [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-programmatic-languages/explore-ampscript) , or the [documentation](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Replace](https://ampscript.guide/replace/) and [RequestParameter](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/) functions. There are more available sources that could be easily found to get started with AMPscript.

In your case, your code translates to:

1. Request parameter "EmailAddress" and then replace any spaces there with the "+" symbol.
2. If it is empty, then do the same but to the "email" parameter.